# Warning when start command mongo

Tags: nginx, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

My server running on Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx.

When I enter the command `mongo` on my server I have this warning:

```
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-07-31T16:59:14.390+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-07-31T16:59:14.391+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Cannot detect if NUMA interleaving is enabled. Failed to probe "/sys/devices/system/node/node1": Permission denied
2016-07-31T16:59:14.391+0200 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-07-31T16:59:14.391+0200 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage": Permission denied
2016-07-31T16:59:14.391+0200 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-07-31T16:59:14.391+0200 W CONTROL  [initandlisten] Failed to probe "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage": Permission denied
2016-07-31T16:59:14.391+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem when I added the security authorization in /etc/mongod.conf :

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

I don't have warnings anymore.